# Reference to "this" is null in function called by redux-saga call

Tags: javascript, typescript, closures, redux-saga

I'm learning `redux-saga` and I'm trying to integrate it into a project that uses an API that is generated with openapi-generator which produces output like the following:

```
async loginUser(body: Login): Promise<LoginResponse> {
    debugger;
    const response = await this.loginUserRaw({ body: body });
    return await response.value();
}
```

And `loginUserRaw` is a function that performs the actual login. Then, I have the following saga:

```
function* login(action:Login) {
    try{
        const response = yield call(User.loginUser, action);
        yield result(LOGIN_SUCCESS, response)
    }catch(e){
        yield result(LOGIN_FAILURE, e)
    }
}
```

When this runs, I get an error in my API method's `await this.loginUserRaw({ body: body });` line:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'loginUserRaw' of null`

I debug it and see that `this` is null. When I bind the function explicitly in the saga:

`const response = yield call(User.loginUser.bind(User), action);`

It works, but I don't wanna bind it every time I call a function. How can I get saga to work without explicitly binding the function? (I can't change the generated code and remove `this` either)

Comment: Can you post the part of the class that includes loginUserRaw?

Comment: @JayKariesch if you mean the call to the function, I've already posted it. if you mean the function definition itself, it's just a regular async function that returns a promise. I don't think this is any way relevant though, the problem has nothing to do with the `loginUserRaw` function itself, it's the parent object reference being null anyway.

Comment: imo. I'd not make `User` a class, but rather a module. On the other hand, I have no clue what else `User` is supposed to handle, and wether that warrants a class. Anyways, try to get rid of the `this` part in `this.loginUserRaw`. These are static functions, not methods of some object instance.

Comment: @Thomas as I've already said, that is *autogenerated code*, I can't change it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Context in Javascript is dynamic based on the way you've written your code

```
const loginUser = User.loginUser
loginUser() // context lost, because there is no longer `User.` in front of it
```

Same applies when you pass a function as an parameter. This means that you have to provide the `call` effect context in some way. The `bind` method is one option, however the effect itself supports multiple ways of providing context. You can find them in the official docs https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callcontext-fn-args, here is the short version of it:

Possible ways to pass context:

```
call([context, fn], ...args)
call([context, fnName], ...args)
call({context, fn}, ...args)
```

So for example you can do the following:

```
const response = yield call([User, User.loginUser], action);
```

Comment: Well, it's still not exactly what I want, but I think there isn't any other option.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Yah, I am not huge fan of this either. Another option is just not to use the `call` effect, but instead call the function directly. That makes testing bit more annoying though + you need to make sure that the called function won't trigger a synchronous store.dispatch.

Comment: unfortunately the call is async and saga apparently doesn't support async functions

Comment: Sagas don't use async/await for its API, but it is still normal Javascript so you can use whatever syntax you want for your own stuff. When you call an async function it returns a Promise and saga can handle promises. Just do `const response = yield User.loginUser(action);` and it will work.

Comment: What is the downside of writing `const response = yield User.loginUser(action);` instead of `const response = yield call([User, User.loginUser], action);`?