# Why can't I make a redux-saga call on react-query refetchQueries?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-saga, react-query

I'm trying to `yield` the method `refetchQueries` without success as below:

```
    yield call(queryClient.refetchQueries,
      [EReactQueryKeys.LIST_MIX, urlParams.sceneId],
      { active: true, exact: true }
    );
```

This throws no errors but the `call` don't call the method and nothing happens, but as far as I know the `call` effect can call promised methods, I use that behavior when call my services, just like this:

```
    yield call(MixService.create, urlParams, mixName);
```

This works just fine even with the `MixService.create` being a `async` method and not a generator.

Even further, why, if I create an `async` wrapper, it works as expected? It leads me to a bigger doubt of "why can't I just `call` and `yield` this method?"

```
    const wrapper = async (sceneId: string) => queryClient.refetchQueries(
      [EReactQueryKeys.LIST_MIX, sceneId],
      { active: true, exact: true },
    );

    yield call(wrapper, urlParams.sceneId); // Inside my saga fn
```

If I get the type or the return of `refetchQueries` I get that this is a promise too, but for some reason the `refetchQueries` don't work as expected when called. If I run the method without the `call` effect as below, it works fine:

```
    queryClient.refetchQueries(
      [EReactQueryKeys.LIST_MIX, urlParams.sceneId],
      { active: true, exact: true },
    );
```

Did I'm missing something about the behavior of the `call` effect or `refetchQueries`?

Comment: Aren't you just losing context? Try ` yield call([queryClient, queryClient.refetchQueries], [EReactQueryKeys.LIST_MIX, urlParams.sceneId], { active: true, exact: true });`

Comment: You're precisely right, this solution works! But what is that context loss and why on the other class method it don't need it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397875/reference-to-this-is-null-in-function-called-by-redux-saga-call/58398357#58398357